# Viewing GPS coordinates on Trimble Geoxh 6000

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, trimble

I read that the point coordinate system is proprietary.

What software do I need to view the points as gps coordinates and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Trimble SSF format to shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80868/converting-trimble-ssf-format-to-shapefile)

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/can-ssf-files-from-trimble-gps-be-imported-as-features-to-display-in-arcmap

Comment: What "point coordinate system" are you talking about? I think the Geo 6000 operating system included GPS Controller, which lets you see Latitudes and Longitudes directly. No need to use any additional software.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about a Trimble Total Station, I would argue this is more of a Surveying question than GIS due to software. Luckily, I'm educated in both.

One of Trimble's proprietary data visualizer is Trimble Business Center. You can go into TBC and filter by measured points only. Remove Backsights, legal tie-in and Survey Evidence if it's not important and you believe your data is accurate.

Alternatively, you can get in with FieldGenius 10 but I'm unsure if it's open-source, I doubt since it's a MicroSurvey product.

PS. The only proprietary GCS/PCS are the one's you make yourself. You've probably used a Local or State/Provincial projection. Feel free to share it if you want.